# Is it possible to setup CORS Anywhere on localhost?

Tags: codeigniter, heroku, web-scraping, cors, cors-anywhere

I am building a web scraper as a small project (using [CodeIgniter](https://codeigniter.com/)). Due to CORS policy, I am not allowed to get data from some sites.

To bypass that, I am using Rob Wu's [CORS Anywhere](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere). I'm prepending the [cors_url](https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/) to the URL I'm scraping data off of.

Everything works fine until I hit the maximum allowed limit of 200 requests per hour. After hitting 200 times, I get an [HTTP status code: 429](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429) (*Too many requests*).

[Screenshot showing Network log.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dp66V.png)

As per the documentation, we can create an instance of our own server.js on **Heroku**. But, what I want to do is, to set it up locally for my local Apache server (**localhost**), just to test out the things first.

---

Some sample code:

```
var url = "http://example.com/";
var cors_url = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";

$.ajax({
    method:'GET',
    url : cors_url + url,
    success : function(response){
            //data_scraping_logic...
    }
}
```

Comment: You would just save the sample cors server code and run it with node.

Comment: Can you please clarify more on that? How can I do that with CodeIgniter? I'm totally new to this concept.

Comment: I believe cors-anywhere has a rate limit built in. The limit is accessed from process.env so I don't know why it would still worked.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- Install the latest node
- save the repo example code as cors.js (I'll paste it below)
- do `npm install cors-anywhere`
- run `node cors` - now it's running on localhost:8080

## sample code

```
// Listen on a specific host via the HOST environment variable
var host = process.env.HOST || '0.0.0.0';
// Listen on a specific port via the PORT environment variable
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

var cors_proxy = require('cors-anywhere');
cors_proxy.createServer({
    originWhitelist: [], // Allow all origins
    // requireHeader: ['origin', 'x-requested-with'],
    // removeHeaders: ['cookie', 'cookie2']
}).listen(port, host, function() {
    console.log('Running CORS Anywhere on ' + host + ':' + port);
});
```