# Code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND', requireStack[] node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm busy with a project which creates a puppy database table in MySQL Workbench. It also makes use of WAMP server. I've created the puppy module as well as the puppy seeder. I have tried to run 'node seed.js' in the terminal in VS Code however I get the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\PaigeF\OneDrive - (company name here which I have removed intetionally)\Desktop\Sequelize-Pet-App\seed.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

Here is my Puppy.model.js code:

```
const { DataTypes, Model } = require('sequelize');

class Puppy extends Model { }

Puppy.init({
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
    },
    age: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    favFood: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true,
    },
},
    {
        sequelize,
        tableName: 'puppies',
        modelName: 'Puppy',
    });

model.exports = Puppy;
```

Here is my puppy.test.seeder.js code:

```
module.exports.seed = async () => {
    const Puppy = require('./puppy.model');
    Puppy.sequelize.sync();
}
```

And finally here is my seed.js code:

```
require('./Library/connection');
const Puppy = require('./modules/puppy.test.seeder');

seed();
async function seed() {
    console.log('Seeding Completed');
    process.exit();
}
```

I know this might not be the best/most efficient way, however, this is the layout that my company wants me to use.

Thanks for all and any help/advise!

Comment: I think that you need to export the module of the `seed.js`.
Something like `module.exports`.

Comment: run in a separate console window (windows), or terminal (linux); u'll get rid of that error when u're at the dir of seed.js

Comment: @PaigeF got any solution for this

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the issue and solved it by firstly following these instructions... https://stackoverflow.com/a/60823141/9594269

but my `cors.js` file was in the \src folder so it could not find the file and threw this error.

Also, because I was using Visual Studio for my main project, when I got it to work it locked the terminal while it was running.

The solution was to run a windows command prompt with administrator privileges, cd to the relevant folder with cors.js in, and the type "node cors" and it worked to run it in a seperate window, so I could then work with my main project in Visual Studio.

@Dee should take the credit for this in the comments section, but the above should clarify the process.

This gets it running but whether it then works to solve the CORS error from a Localhost is another issue - https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/issues/217